# MacOS link library containing CoreBluetooth framework

Tags: java, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, jna

I'm attempting to use *[Java Native Access](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)* (*JNA*) to provide a *Java* interface to the *[CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth)* framework that's an integral part *MacOS* (version 12.1, in my case).

It appears that I need access to a *MacOS* link library in order for *JNA* to determine the elements of the interface that are available. However, I can't seem to locate the link library file that provides the classes, methods, etc. for this framework.

I've looked inside the following bundles with no success:

- `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework`
- `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework`
- `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreBluetoothUI.framework`

I've scanned the contents of `/usr/lib` too, but I'm not seeing anything related to `CoreBluetooth`, and I don't want to have to look at the contents of every `.dylib` file on the system.

Any suggestions where I can find this file? Or are there any other ways I can setup a *JNA* interface to `CoreBluetooth`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just load the library by name in JNA as usual (version 5.6 or greater).

```java
public interface CoreBluetooth extends Library {

    CoreBluetooth INSTANCE = Native.load("CoreBluetooth", CoreBluetooth.class);

    // mappings
}
```

You won't find it in the filesystem in macOS 11 or later, however.  From the [macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11_0_1-release-notes):

> New in macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, the system ships with a built-in dynamic linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change, copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem. Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail. Instead, check for library presence by attempting to dlopen() the path, which will correctly check for the library in the cache.

JNA 5.6 was updated to use this new behavior.

That said, I do have a copy of the framework, or at least the header files, on my system under the following path:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/
```

That's not useful for loading into JNA but it does provide header files if the online documentation is insufficient.  I'm not sure why you don't have it in your own Command Line tools path or how my installation differs from yours.

Comment: Interesting about the library cache. I would never have thought of that. But there are still plenty of `.dylib` system library files on the filesystem, so they're inconsistent in applying that rule. :-) I'll give that a try and will accept your answer if that does the trick. BTW, the command line tools I have are up-to-date, and are not for version 10. The `MacOSX.sdk` portion of the path is a _symlink_ for `MacOSX12.1.sdk` on my machine, and the `MacOSX11.3.sdk` is there too.